# Find many members of a list in an other! Python

Tags: python, list

i have problems to  find list members in an other array. It doesn't print any errors but it prints anything.. This is my code.. I wanna search "parole" in the frequenzaparolespamglob, which is a list..This is wrong code.. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance for the attention...

```js
requenzaparolehamglob=Counter()
i=0
while i < len(frequenzaparoleham):
    frequenzaparolehamglob= frequenzaparolehamglob + frequenzaparoleham[i]
    i=i+1

frequenzaparolespamglob=Counter()
i=0
while i < len(frequenzaparolespam):
    frequenzaparolespamglob= frequenzaparolespamglob + frequenzaparolespam[i]
    i=i+1

sommafreqspam= sum(frequenzaparolespamglob.values())

sommafreqham= sum(frequenzaparolehamglob.values())


frequenzaparolespamglob=sorted(list(collections.Counter(frequenzaparolespamglob).items()))
frequenzaparolehamglob=sorted(list(collections.Counter(frequenzaparolehamglob).items()))

inputemail = input('Inserisci una email:')
parole = nltk.word_tokenize(inputemail)
parole=[i for i in parole if i not in listastop]
parole = rimuovipunteggiatura.tokenize (str(parole))
parole=[i for i in parole if i.isalpha()]
parole=[ps.stem(parola) for parola in parole]
print(len(parole))
parole=list(parole)

while i <len(parole):
    while i < len(frequenzaparolespamglob):
        if parole[i] in frequenzaparolespamglob[i]:
            print('Found a entry:', parole[i])
```

Comment: Your code is based on some uninitialized variables. Please create a working example!

Comment: I'm guessing the error is here `if parole[i] in frequenzaparolespamglob[i]:`. Remove the `i` index on `frequenzaparolespamglob` since you're not searching the whole list.

Comment: Wait, what even is `i` at the end? It's not being incremented anywhere that I can see, so what's happening with the `while` loops? It's possible that it's using the value from somewhere near the top, and the `while` loops never even start. It's hard to follow what's going on.

Comment: Klaus is only a part of code.. The whole code is 300 rows.. Thanks but this  isn't the error..

Comment: You means " print('Found a entry:', parole[i])" ?

Comment: No, I'm pointing out two issues. First, there's no initialisation of `i = 0` for the `while` loops at the bottom, nor is there `i += 1` within the loops. Second, I think that `frequenzaparolespamglob` is a flat list, so if you add an `i` index to it, then you're only looking at one element in the list. As a separate note, you should consider using `_` or something to break these names up. They're very similar it's really not easy to differentiate between them